# How to escape a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I have a while loop in Main() which goes through several methods. Although one method named `ScanChanges()` has an if / else statement, in the case of `if`, it must jump to `Thread.Sleep(10000)` (at the end of the loop).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    while (true)
    {
        ChangeFiles();    
        ScanChanges();    
        TrimFolder();    
        TrimFile();    
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}    

private static void ChangeFiles()
{
    // code here
}

private static void ScanChanges()
{
} 

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("input.txt");
if (fi.Length > 0)
{
    // How to Escape loop??
}
else
{
    Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c test.exe -f input.txt > output.txt").WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make ScanChanges return some value indicating whether you must skip to the end of the loop:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                ChangeFiles();

                bool changes = ScanChanges();

                if (!changes) 
                {
                    TrimFolder();

                    TrimFile();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }


private static void ChangeFiles()
{
  // code here
}

private static bool ScanChanges()
{
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("input.txt");
     if (fi.Length > 0)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c test.exe -f input.txt > output.txt").WaitForExit();

         return false;
      }      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have `ScanChanges` return a `bool` if you've reached that `if` statement within `ScanChanges`, and then have another `if` statement in the while loop that skips over those two procedures if `ScanChanges` comes back true.

Answer (score 0):

Make the return value out of ScanChanges, it may be boolean if it going to break loop return true else return false.

Then set break loop condition in main.

Answer (score 0):

Use break to get out of the loop.

```
if (fi.Length > 0)
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: Same holds for this comment, you can't use `break` directly in another method - use jonsca's method.